# Form will not submit, but instead loads a blank page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I'm trying to create a simple form, to add users to a MySQL Database.

I'm currently loading the pages into the main content box using AJAX, whenever I load the form into the main content box, It will load fine.

However, When I click Submit, the page reloads into nothing, and when I check the database, the user has not been added.

```
<form method=\"post\" action=\"add_user.php?action=register\">
<b>Username:</b><td><input name=\"username_register\" MAXLENGTH=\"16\"><br />
<b>Email Address:</b><input name=\"email_register\"><br />
<b>Password:</b><input name=\"password_register\"><br />
<b>Mobile Number:</b><input name=\"mob_register\"><br />
<b>Home Number:</b><input name=\"home_register\"><br />
<b>Staff Name:</b> <td><input name=\"name_register\"><br />
<b>Position:</b><select name=\"position_register\">
<option value=\"3\">Sales Assistant</option>
<option value=\"2\">Team Leader</option>
<input type="send value=\"Add User\" accesskey=\"s\">
</form>
```

This is the code I'm currently using, how would I get that to work, without re-loading to a blank page?

Comment: Why does your HTML have all of those back-slashes?  And your `input` tag appears to be very broken.  And your `select` element doesn't have a closing tag.  Honestly, this is *very* invalid HTML.  You'll need to fix it before you should expect any defined behavior from it.

Comment: The back slashes are because it is inside an Echo. So, i would get an error come up if it did not have the backslashes. However, thanks for pointing out the rest of the errors. Also, How is the input tag broken? o.O

Comment: Use a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead, so you do not have to escape...

Comment: So where is your ajax request ? where is your other page that gives you the result to the ajax ? and where is the rest of your php form page we need to see all that to see where you are doing it wrong. `<input type="send value=\"Add User\" accesskey=\"s\">` should have been `<input type="submit" name="send" value=\"Add User\" accesskey=\"s\">`

Comment: Regarding the input tag: "send" is not a valid type as far as I know, and you don't have a closing double-quote for the type. Assuming it should appear as a button, you probably want `type="submit"`. (Edit: or what Prix said, though the `name` attribute isn't required.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are getting a blank page , this is just a suggestion to find if any errors from php.
If you have not enabled the error logs in php.ini file just enable and check.

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```